# How to make a config file which I can include in my backbone.js project

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I want to make a default config file according to which I will create my view.

I am thinking of something like:

```
var Application = {};
Application.Config = {
   ViewerModule : {
     width    : '60%',
     height   : '60%',
     maxWidth : '99%',
     minWidth : '1%',
     iconSize : '24*24',
     defaultColor   : 'Green',
     selectedColor  : 'Orange',
     fontColor      : 'Black',
     viewerToolColor: 'White',
     defaultView    : 'Fit To Screen',
     Labels:{
            btnZoomIn     :'Zoom In',
            btnZoomOut    :'Zoom Out',
            btnRotateLeft :'Rotate Left',
            btnRotateRight:'Rotate Right',
            btnFitToScreen:'Fit to Screen',
            btnFullScreen :'Full Screen',
            btnSaveAs     :'Zoom In',
            btnExport     :'Zoom Out',
            btnPopOut     :'Rotate Left',
            btnEmail      :'Rotate Right',
            btnPdfConverter:'Fit to Screen',
            btnSetting    :'Settings'           
     }
   }
}
```

And so when I create my view in backbone, I can use this config value to define default values of my Backbone View.

One thing I thought was save values from config file to a backbone model and create a view with that model.

However, I am not sure if this is the right thing.

Can share me your thoughts or examples on how I can achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could mix in your config object into the prototype of your view with [`_.defaults`](http://underscorejs.org/#defaults) if you want to set defaults for your views, with [`_.extend`](http://underscorejs.org/#extend) if you prefer to force the values.

For example,

```
var Application = {};
Application.Config = {};
Application.Config.ViewerModule = {
    width: '60%',
    height: '60%'
};

var V = Backbone.View.extend({
    width: '50%'
});
_.defaults(V.prototype, Application.Config.ViewerModule);

var v = new V();
console.log(v.width, v.height);
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/VX7SY/

Comment: This works for my case. Its a good solution. Thanks for telling me something i didnt knew before :)
For the moment, i just made a json file and import the content is a json model. Using that model value to pass to a view. Because i cant put default value inside my code. It has to be outside

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using inheritance to overcome this problem? Instead of a config you could have a `BaseView` that has the aforementioned properties as view `options`. This way, these values could be overwritten in the implementation of your child view, or parsed in during construction of the child view.

Here's a crude example:

```
var BaseView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.options = {
            'Example': 'Foobar',
            'OverrideMe': 'Moo'
        };
    }
})

, ChildView = BaseView.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.options.Example = 'Something else';  
    }
})

, impl = new ChildView({'OverrideMe': 'Another thing'});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4GL6b/) that shows it working.

Comment: Seems promising however my requirement is 'i have to make a config file which is outside of code and can be edited easily by client'.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you, i suggest You use [Model defaults](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-defaults), and here you can see simple example. Or you can use your config like json object, but by the way you must to create empty Model and set config json to model(=new Model)

Comment: Even i was thinking to use Model default first to save default configuration value, however i cannot do that because my client want a configuration file where he can do changes instead of backbone model. And so, what i need to do is create a backbone model with those configuration setting.  I think i will try going with second method of you, make a config like json object and fill those value in a backbone model.